# Erro ao iniciar PostgreSQL - [FALHOU]

Tags: postgresql, linux, centos, postgresql-10, dbase

Estou tentando subir a base de dados, porém quando dou o comando service postgresql-9.1 start aparece a seguinte mensagem:

Iniciando servico postgresql-9.1 : [FALHOU].

Fui até o arquivo de log com comando tail -f postgresql-Mon.log e apareceu os seguintes registros.

[image: Imagem]

Comment: Olha esse post falando sobre --- http://avds.eti.br/redes-de-computadores/linux/como-instalar-o-postgre-e-agadmin-no-linux/217/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `PostgreSQL` utiliza o modelo `MVCC (Multiversion Concurrency Control)` para controle das transações e nele os Multixact IDs são utilizados para o controle de lock de registros. Ele é implementado como um inteiro de 32 bits. Por causa deste limite um servidor rodando muitas transações pode sofrer o "transaction ID wraparound" quando o contador retorna a zero e todas as transações efetivamente anteriores passam a ser encaradas como futuras.

A solução para impedir isso é avaliar quando é necessário rodar um VACUUM (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-vacuumdb.html). O PostgreSQL também implementa uma feature opcional, mas recomendada, denominada autovacuum (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html) que faz a avaliação periódica e automaticamente, bastando habilitá-la.

Apenas para lembrar: a versão 9.1 deixou de receber suporte e atualizações desde 2016, avalie fazer um upgrade para uma versão mais recente, a versão atual é a 12.0.

Comment: Então devo reinstalar o postgresql ?, pois como já ocorreu o erro não tem como rodar o VACUUM certo ?

Comment: Não precisa reinstalar. Tente rodar o postgres em single mode `postgres --single -D /data/seu_diretório` e a seguir rode o vacuum para cada um dos bancos de sua instalação. Rode de preferência com super-usuário. Como, me parece, você não domina todas as atividades de administração do PosrgreSQL talvez uma consultoria especializada possa ajuda-lo mais efetivamente.

Comment: Estou usando o usuario root, porém está dando erro no comando       
 postgres --single -D /usr/pgsql-9.1/                                                              
bash postgres: command not found

Comment: Então coloque o caminho completo do comando postgres ou acerte o path. Volto a insistir: se os dados de seu banco são valiosos e como, tudo indica, você não tem intimidade com a administração do PostgreSQL avalie com a devida atenção a contratação de uma consultoria especializada.